# Gitlab SSH Key | must the ssh have the same username as gitlab account

Tags: ssh, permissions, gitlab, ssh-keygen

## Problem

Does the 'user@host' of the `id_rsa.pub` need to match with the actual machine `username - host`  and then with the  username in Gitlab?

#### Example:

- Gitlab username name: **@john.doe**
- Ubuntu Machine hostname command `hostname`: **JOHNDOE**
- Ubuntu username: `mark`
- Username in the `id_rsa.pub`: `...fsdfsdfsdfsd mark@JOHNDOE`

So as you can see, my user in Ubuntu is `mark` and the ssh rsa key generated has a `mark@JOHNDOE` as last domain. But should it be `john.doe@JOHNDOE` instead **(both in Ubuntu user and in the ssh pub key)**?

And let's say that for some reason **I cannot change the user in my Ubuntu machine**.

I honestly think the answer is **no** and the issue is on my *user in Gitlab that has some missing permissions or some network related problem*, and I'm just paranoid but just to make sure that is not related with the ssh keys.
I think the ssh key just need to match the one in Gitlab and the username in the key has nothing to do (because actually, you can change it with command `-C "john.doe@JOHNDOE"` which is a **Comment** and anyway it still gives me errors. But again I have the doubt is **ALSO** the username of the Ubuntu must be `john.doe`

### Command run / Troubleshot

- **OS:**  `Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS on Windows 10 x86_64` (WSL)
- **I need to connect via VPN (all other https services works via Browser so it should be fine)**

**Creating ssh**

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048
```

**Add SSH**

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub 
# Then copy the key to gitlba key - etc..
```

**Also try do**

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add -D
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

#### Error

**Do a git clone**

```
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

**Connecting**

```
ssh -T git@gitlab.example.com
banner exchange: Connection to [here the IP but removed] port 22: Connection timed out
```

Comment: The username and hostname of the machine you are using does not need to match the 'user@host' of the id_rsa.pub file, and should not affect your ability to clone a Gitlab repository. It could either be your network, permissions on your Gitlab account or Gitlab is having problems.

Comment: Yes excatly that's what I think. But just want to make sure is not that at least so I don't think about it not more.

Comment: If you have been able to clone the private repo before without problems, and you have changed nothing. It's most likely a network issue. If not, maybe try generating a new ssh key on your local computer and updating the ssh key in your account on Gitlab.

Comment: Yes I do it like a shameful amount of times  : ). Then I guess is network or user related on Gitlab side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the problem is the VPN software that I used.
As [@Raya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13504048/raya) pointed out the answer to my question is:

#### **No, the user in the ssh public key does not matter**

As soon as I changed the VPN it start to work therefore the problem was **Network related**

Will auto-post the answer and mark as accepted, but won't close the question so if anyone has better information can add it.

Comment: Maybe I have a similar issue. What changes regarding your vpn connection did you make?

Comment: VPN is managed by my company and never got the solution. as a matter of fact it started to work after some time so really can't find the root cause. Furthermore it could have been something related to WSL as well.  Are you using Windows WSL?

Comment: No, not using WSL. It is just weird. Always worked generating a key pair, upload key to gitlab, done. Now it gives permission denied. Anyway, thx for your response!

Comment: ok @Gerros so is something different, and good for u because WSL is creating more isues than fixing them sometimes..anyways... good luck ;)